# Best practice to record creator of a file

Tags: windows, software-design, ntfs

I want to only warn my users that they are overwriting a file if it wasn't generated by my program.

I thought the best approach might be store another file like `Package.docx.info` which contains the date modified at which my program generated the file and if it s the same then allow overwriting.

I was wondering what the standard approach is for this kind of thing. My only concern is that my user could be confused by the additional file or if they move the file they might lose that information.

Is there a standard approach for storing metadata about a file on Windows?

Comment: A common solution to storing metadata for a file is to place it inside an [Alternate Data Stream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-fscc/e2b19412-a925-4360-b009-86e3b8a020c8).

Comment: @IInspectable, if a user were to modify the file normally, would the alternate data stream be wiped?

Comment: Modifying the main stream of a file has no effect on any other data streams.